# HTML Layout with floats

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I'm trying to create the following layout with `float: left` and the minimum amount of DOM.

[image: layout-good]

Using the code below it doesn't work (obviously), and I get this result:

[image: layout-bad]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .out {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .in {
        float: left;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="out">
        <div class="in" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; background: red;"></div>
        <div class="in" style="width: 50%; height: 100%; background: green;"></div>
        <div class="in" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; background: blue;"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

so is there a way to do it?

**IMPORTANT NOTES!**

- I must use `float: left` because of a constraint from other layouts
- I can't use `flex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a container around the two smaller ones so that they are contained together. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ce0nmase/

As you can see in the `html`, I have this code:

```
<div class="in" style="width: 50%; height: 100%; background: red;">
    <div class="in" style="width: 100%; height: 50%; background: blue;"></div>
    <div class="in" style="width: 100%; height: 50%; background: yellow;"></div>
</div>
```

This means that you have two 50% containers, one of which is the full height. Then in your second one, you have two more containers which both have 50% height.

---

EDIT:

Alternatively, you can add `float:right;` to the full height box.

http://jsfiddle.net/ce0nmase/1/

Comment: this approach is fine and i'm aware of it, but i'm trying to avoid unnecessary containers if I can (I'm not searching for a trivial solution)

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*-------------
    Global
---------------*/

#wrapper {
  width:100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: black solid 1px;
}

#red {
  background:red;
  width:50%;
  min-height:100px;
}

#blue {
  background:blue;
  width:50%;
  min-height:100px;
}

#green{
  background:green;
  width:50%;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.float-left{
  float:left;
}

.float-right{
  float:right;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
}

.clearfix:after{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
    <div id="red" class="float-left">
      red
    </div>
    <div id="green" class="float-right">
      green
    </div>
    <div id="blue" class="float-right">
      blue
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```